# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter' with tkinter on fedora

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm, pysimplegui

i'm on Fedora 34, and I can't use PySimpleGUI, because tkinter won't be installed.
He put "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'" when I enter `import PySimpleGUI as sg`

```
>>> import PySimpleGUI as sg
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/home/meblikea/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
   from .PySimpleGUI import *
 File "/home/meblikea/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 95, in <module>
   import tkinter as tk
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
   import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I already tried `sudo dnf install python3-tkinter`, and he said he is already installed.

I already tried to install tk and future, but he print

```
Requirement already satisfied: future in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.18.2)
```

Can you help me please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

tkinter is in standart library. which editor do you use?

So if you use PyCharm and have red underlined text like these :

[image]

(don't matter about the content).
You can click on the red underlined text, and import tkinter. If that does not work, try this: `pip install python-tk`

Comment: PyCharm, as I can see from tags.

Comment: Why do you have 2 answers, remove one and include the other into a single one