# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter' on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

i'm trying to put some code in jupyter notebook, and for that, i need to import tkinter.

I'm doing this

```
from tkinter import *
```

And i have this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-67079ccbcb8c> in <module>
      1 import nltk
----> 2 from tkinter import *
      3 from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections
      4 from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
      5 import string

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py in <module>
     34 import sys
     35 
---> 36 import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
     37 TclError = _tkinter.TclError
     38 from tkinter.constants import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

But when i'm doing in local `python3 script.py` everything is working.
And i have tkinter in my pc. I'm using Fedora.
I've already tried to reinstall but nothing is working. Anyone have a clue ?

Comment: Did you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67706085/16775594)?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin yes, but it's giving me : ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-tk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-tk

Comment: Wait -- I was mixed up there. You need to install `tkinter` using _system_ commands, not `python3`. Sorry for the confusion :D! Try searching `[python] install tkinter fedora` on Stack Overflow. Judging by a brief search, you can use `sudo yum install tkinter` or `yum install tkinter`.

Comment: When i'm trying to install with yum, they're detecting an very old version in python2 Package python2-tkinter-2.7.18-1.fc30.x86_64 ibs already installed.
(but i have a version of python3 because when i'm doing sudo yum install python3-tkinter.x86_64 i have Package python3-tkinter-3.7.7-1.fc30.x86_64 is already installed.).

Comment: Hmm... I'm sorry, I'm afraid that I won't be of much more help here. I don't use Fedora or Jupyter notebooks, so I'm not familiar with them enough to know what's wrong here :-(.

Comment: no problem, thank you for the clues :)

Comment: Maybe you have two Pythons installed and you run jupyter with one Python but `python script.py` runs it with other Python. In Jupyter you can use `sys.executable()` to get `/full/path/to/python` and compare it with `which python` in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anwser of furas was correct. My problem was I had two python3 and jupyter notebook didn't have the good version.

Basically, to fix this problem :

```
 $which python

-> alias python='/usr/bin/python3.7'
    /usr/bin/python3.7
```

Now i know the path of the python with my tkinter.
I just need to find the kernel of my jupyter notebook and update the kernel.json with the path of my actual python

```
$jupyter kernelspec list
-> Available kernels:
    python3    /home/Natko/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
$nano  /home/Natko/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json
```

When i'm opening my kernel.json i have

```
{
 "argv": [
  "python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python",
}
```

I just need to add the path of my python3

```
{
 "argv": [
  "python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python",
 "env": {
     "PYTHONPATH": "/usr/bin/"
 }
}
```

And now, i can use tkinter (or another) in jupyter notebook